# Fill polygons in Python turtle with color according to size

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Random(?) generated polygons drawn by Turtle need to be filled with colors according to their size, but won't fill the finished shape.
Here is the code that I have written already.

```
import turtle, random

def drawpoly (sTurtle, sSides, sLength):
    for i in range (sSides):
        sTurtle.begin_fill()
        sTurtle.forward(sLength)
        sTurtle.left(360/sSides)
        sTurtle.end_fill()

sides = random.randint (3, 21)
size = random.randint (30, 200)

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')

mac = turtle.Turtle()
mac.color('black')
mac.fillcolor()
mac.pensize(3)

for each in (size, sides):
    if each <= 99:
        mac.fillcolor('red')
    elif each <= 149:
        mac.fillcolor('white')
    elif each >149:
        mac.fillcolor('blue')

drawpoly(mac, sides, size)
```

In the end, most of what I try ends up changing only the Turtle line colors.  I can't seem to get the (semi random) polygon that Mac (the turtle) draws to fill with color.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem I found is this code:

```
for i in range (sSides):
    sTurtle.begin_fill()
    sTurtle.forward(sLength)
    sTurtle.left(360/sSides)
    sTurtle.end_fill()
```

You're trying to fill lines instead of polygons.  What you really want is:

```
sTurtle.begin_fill()
for i in range (sSides):
    sTurtle.forward(sLength)
    sTurtle.left(360/sSides)
sTurtle.end_fill()
```

This code is simply confusing:

```
for each in (size, sides):
    if each <= 99:
        mac.fillcolor('red')
    elif each <= 149:
        mac.fillcolor('white')
    elif each >149:
        mac.fillcolor('blue')
```

You say you're coloring based on *size* but then override that in the end and color by *sides*.  Here's my rework of your code that addresses both issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def drawpoly(sTurtle, sSides, sLength):
    sTurtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(sSides):
        sTurtle.forward(sLength)
        sTurtle.left(360 / sSides)
    sTurtle.end_fill()

sides = randint(3, 21)
size = randint(30, 200)

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')

mac = Turtle()
mac.pensize(3)

if size < 100:
    mac.fillcolor('red')
elif size < 150:
    mac.fillcolor('white')
else:
    mac.fillcolor('blue')

drawpoly(mac, sides, size)

wn.exitonclick()
```